# Summing specific attributes of a data frame in r

Tags: r, loops, dataframe, attributes

I have a data frame created that is 22,000 objects of 8 variables. The two vectors that I am concerned with at this point and that are relevant to the question are vect1 and vect2. There are 4 unique values that comprise vect1, all four elements are repeated a various number of times. What I can't seem to figure out is how to loop through the data frame and find the mean, median, mode or any other statistical calculation for all values of vect1, with respect to its vect2 value. Or for that matter, sum all the values in vect2 that have a specific vect1 value.

Answer (score 0):

We can use `dplyr`

```
library(dplyr)
df1 %>%
    group_by(vect1) %>%
    summarise_each(funs(sum, mean, median, Mode), vect2)
```

where `Mode` is

```
Mode <- function(x) {
 ux <- unique(x)
 ux[which.max(tabulate(match(x, ux)))]
}
```

Comment: When I attempt to implement this I receive this ``Error: invalid subscript type 'integer'``

Comment: @stinsrob  You haven't showed any reproducible example.  So, i can't comment

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this will help...

```
> set.seed(22)
> df2 <- data.frame(replicate(8,sample(0:50,22000,rep=TRUE)))
> Mode <- function(x) {
+ ux <- unique(x)
+ ux[which.max(tabulate(match(x, ux)))]
+ }
> library(dplyr)
> df2 %>%
+ group_by(X1) %>%
+ summarise_each(funs(sum, mean, median, Mode), X2)
Source: local data frame [51 x 5]

      X1   sum     mean median  Mode
   (int) (int)    (dbl)  (dbl) (int)
1      0 10757 25.55107   25.0    38
2      1 11198 24.18575   24.0     2
3      2 10682 24.66975   25.0    46
4      3 11168 26.15457   26.0    17
5      4 10430 25.68966   26.5    26
6      5 10840 24.63636   25.0    33
7      6 11134 24.57837   25.0     5
8      7 10946 25.22120   26.0    31
9      8 11761 25.79167   27.0    28
10     9 11126 24.94619   26.0    34
..   ...   ...      ...    ...   ...
```

if you could provide a sample of the data that would help but the above should help clarify the answer provided by Akrun. In general, it would be great to see a line of the data or simply a description of the Dataframe you are referring to. For example:

```
> str(df2)
'data.frame':   22000 obs. of  8 variables:
 $ X1: int  15 24 50 26 43 36 31 37 21 19 ...
 $ X2: int  33 45 26 6 3 6 14 47 29 21 ...
 $ X3: int  48 23 12 10 17 33 28 20 18 39 ...
 $ X4: int  29 10 10 38 11 5 35 9 31 37 ...
 $ X5: int  33 25 43 16 35 12 24 16 2 50 ...
 $ X6: int  3 18 12 8 36 30 20 1 4 0 ...
 $ X7: int  24 23 47 25 5 25 41 38 45 19 ...
 $ X8: int  28 25 15 33 29 29 45 38 8 14 ...
```

I hope the above helps.

Take care
T.